# MongoDB: How to merge a BSON backup with a '.wt' back-up

Tags: mongodb, merge

I am trying to merge a mongodb deployment with a previous back-up due to some processing that took place on the data. I have downloaded and extracted the backup to recover the '.wt' files and can set up a local deployment from the '.bson' files of the original database at a later point in time using mongorestore. How can I combine the two sets of data?

Mongorestore doesn't seem to handle the '.wt' file type to complete the merge.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use *.wt files with `mongorestore`. What you can do, is to copy all files into a new folder and start a `mongod` instance using this folder, e.g. `mongod --dbpath <the path name>` Then you can copy the data following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554762/how-to-copy-a-collection-from-one-database-to-another-in-mongodb/67077465#67077465 to you new database.